# Nassi Shneiderman diagram: Which player has its turn?

Tags: variables, diagrams, logic

I am trying to program a little game and for that I need to determine which's players turn. I am solving it firstly with a Nassi-Schneiderman diagram with a variable *turn* whic can be 1 or 2, but my problem is that I end up with too much branched decision blocks. (In the first round player 1 begins always, the player that loses starts in every other case, if it is a tie player 1 begins)

Do I need another variable or has someone an idea on how I can solve my problem without making it too complicated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need only one [multiple branching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nassi%E2%80%93Shneiderman_diagram) block with 4 alternatives (I try to describe this in text form, drawing the diagram is left as an exercise to the reader, which means you):

Title: choose starting player for next game.

Question: Outcome of the previous game?

- player 1 wins -> player 2 is next
- player 2 wins -> player 1 is next
- tie -> player 1 is next
- no previous game -> player 1 is next

Now place this block inside a loop block with just two sub-blocks "choose starting player for next game" and "play next game".

Side note: as you can see in this example, the expressiveness of Nassi-Shneiderman diagrams is not really better than simple pseudo-code, or even real code in a language like Python (but pseudo-code is way easier to create using a keyboard). That's probably the reason why these kinds of diagrams are not very popular any more today.

Comment: And what would I have to do if there was a tie but the player that didn't had its turn in the previous game start the round instead of player 1? So: tie -> the player plays who wasn't the last one with its turn? Would I have to include a function that decides that or a variable that tells me which player didn't play the last turn?

Comment: @kripss: sure you will need a variable for this case (just as you need a variable for storing the information who won the previous game). But I doubt you need to show this variable in the diagram.

Answer (score 2):

To keep the complexity manageable, you cannot put everything in a single diagram (regardless of what notation you use), but you have to create separate diagrams that represent different portions of the game and/or highlight different aspects.

One split I would make in your case is to use separate diagrams for determining the initial player in a round and for switching turns during a round. The second one would represent a function that receives the initial player as a parameter.